# simple python lxml CRUD?

Tags: python, lxml

I have been looking for a while a python module/API that does something I believe is quite simple:

1. Read an XML file
2. Add/Edit/Remove entries

So far I've found several snippets that interface with complicated object oriented databases, but nothing dead simple as:

```
xml = etree.parse ('file.xml')

xml.add(xpath, new_node(attrs))
xml.remove(xpath)
xml.edit(xpath, new_attrs(attrs))
xml.write()
```

Most surely I'm misunderstanding the API, but some light will be very welcome.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checkout the [lxml.etree tutorial](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html)? It has enough examples to show you how to do most of what you want.

Comment: Yep, I did... somehow I expected the API to be more human-readable, but I guess that's XML ;P

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions from the standard library too. I think `clear()` from [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) should work as desired. On the other hand, if you have no problem with external dependencies, I think, not sure though, that lxml provides a faster solution.